# Executing code in client or server, poly- something or other?

Tags: computer-science

I'm just trying to remember the term for this.

The idea is that you have business logic, such as server-side javascript.

But you transport that logic to execute in the client - allowing you to have one version of the business logic but execute remotely when it is advantageous.

There's a term for this, but I think I filled up my last empty brain cell with something else.

Comment: Do you mean the recent trend found in ECMAScript circles, called [Isomorphic applications](https://medium.com/@ElyseKoGo/an-introduction-to-isomorphic-web-application-architecture-a8c81c42f59)? For example, frameworks like Meteor?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The term I was looking for is Isomorphic applications.